# NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.PackageManager

Tags: java, android, permissions, nfc

receiving this error on app startup

Logcat:

```
-10594/com.example.messageswap E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.messageswap, PID: 10594
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.messageswap/com.example.messageswap.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.PackageManager android.content.Context.getPackageManager()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3194)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.PackageManager android.content.Context.getPackageManager()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageManager(ContextWrapper.java:98)
        at com.example.messageswap.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:63)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1243)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3182)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

I am attempting to allow my android device to receive a permission check to send data over NFC.

MainActivity.java:

```
 PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();

    public void permissionCheck(){
        int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);

        if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE);
        } else {
            //TODO
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE:
                if ((grantResults.length > 0) && (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                    //TODO
                }
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

I understand that since Android 6.0, this was required.
The purpose of the application is to send and receive strings over NFC between Android devices.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is `PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();` a field? then you are calling `getPackageManager` at wrong place/time

Answer (score 2):

According to the stack trace, you're trying to retrieve the PackageManager instance at the init of your `MainActivity` instance. **That is impossible to do so.**

In order to get PackageManager from the Activity, your Activity must be attached to the Application class. That is done in the `attachBaseContext` lifecycle method.

So the issue lies in that line:

```
PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
```

In order to get around this issue, please modify that line of code to be:

```
PackageManager packageManager;
```

and add to your `onCreate` method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    packageManager = getPackageManager();
}
```

That will fix your fatal exception.

**Please note**: That solution is just the base solution to your issue. I suggest that you don't store `PackageManager` in the field at all and every time you need to access `PackageManager` - use the `getPackageManager()` method instead.

Answer (score 0):

NFC is not listed as a dangerous permission https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#NFC therefore it does not need any run time permissions checks (As required for "dangerous" permissions in 6.0 and above)

Therefore the manifest permission of

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />`

is enough